# Unexpected drools behaviour

Tags: java, drools

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior with Drools rules. I have a global variable, myList, which is a collection. I'm modifying this list based on conditions in the when clause of my rules. However, when multiple rules run simultaneously, I'm getting unexpected results.

Here's a simplified example of my rules:

```
global Collection myList

rule "myRule1"
when
    Applicant(experienceInYears == 10)
then
    myList.add("level7");
end
```

```
global Collection myList

rule "myRule2"
when
    Applicant(experienceInYears == 15)
then
    myList.add("level8");
end
```

```
global Collection myList

rule "myRule3"
when
    Applicant(experienceInYears == 5)
then
    myList.add("level3");
end
```

The rules are triggered by different inputs, and in one scenario, a rule ran successfully for experienceInYears = 5, adding "level3" to myList.

However, when a subsequent rule ran for experienceInYears = 15, I expected "level8" to be added to myList, but it still contained "level3". These rules ran almost simultaneously.

In my code, I'm creating a new KieSession each time I execute the rules. However, could the use of global variables in the when clause, combined with concurrent rule execution, be causing this unexpected behavior?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public void executeRules(DomainEventRulesProvider rulesProvider, Object fact, Map<String, Object> globals) throws RuleEvaluationException {
    // Create a new KieSession each time
    final KieContainer kieContainer = droolsKieContainerProvider.getKieContainer(rulesProvider);
    final KieSession session = kieContainer.newKieSession();

   CloseableKieSession closeableSession = new CloseableKieSession(session);
        final KieSession kieSession = closeableSession.getSession();
        if(globals != null) {
            globals.forEach((key, val) -> {
                if (val == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null value passed for global variable: " + key);
                }
                kieSession.setGlobal(key, val);
            });
        }
        setupFactAndFireAllRules(fact, kieSession);
}

// Set up the fact and fire all rules
private void setupFactAndFireAllRules(Object fact, KieSession kieSession) {
    kieSession.insert(fact);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
}
```

I'm using Drools with a singleton KieContainer, but I create a new KieSession for each execution of the function. In this function, I check if my globals map is null; it's essentially a map with a string key and a list value. The list is supposed to be modified by Drools rules.

I suspect that concurrent rule execution may be the cause of the unexpected behavior. Any insights or suggestions on how to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Is there any way I can test the concurrent execution of these rules and find a root cause in case such errors occur

```
 public KieContainer getKieContainer(@NonNull final RulesProvider rulesProvider) {
        if (containerCache.containsKey(rulesProvider.getKieBaseName())) {
            return containerCache.get(rulesProvider.getKieBaseName());
        }

        final KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        final KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
        final KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        final KieModuleModel km = ks.newKieModuleModel();
        final List<Resource> rules = rulesProvider.getRules();
        rules.forEach(kfs::write);
        km.newKieBaseModel(rulesProvider.getKieBaseName())
                .newKieSessionModel(rulesProvider.getKieSessionName())
                .setDefault(true);
        kfs.writeKModuleXML(km.toXML());

        final KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        kb.buildAll();
        if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new KieContainerBuildException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults().toString());
        }

        final KieContainer container = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
        containerCache.put(rulesProvider.getKieBaseName(), container);
        log.info("KieContainer created for : {}", rulesProvider.getKieBaseName());
        return container;
    }
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to spend some time pruning your code down to [mcve] form (and mostly _not_ so you can put it in your post, that's a bonus if you're still stuck at the end, but because forcing yourself to try to reproduce the problem with almost no code, and hardcoded inputs, almost always makes you discover what's really going on, answering your own question)

Answer (score 1):

Your simplified example rules do not show the issue you are seeing.

They're very nice, mutually exclusive rules. That means that, given a single input (eg. `Applicant{ experienceInYears: X }` ), at most one rule will ever fire. This is because if X is 5, then only "myRule3" is valid; same as if X is 15, only "myRule2" meets the criteria; and so on.

For the 3 example rules you've shown, given only these rules and a given input, you will only ever see up to 1 value in the global. Note that if the experienceInYears is not 5, 10, or 15, the global list would be expected to be empty (or, at least, as empty as it was prior to firing the rules.)

---

Buried in your post is this seemingly innocuous secondary question:

> In my code, I'm creating a new KieSession each time I execute the rules. However, could the use of global variables in the when clause, combined with concurrent rule execution, be causing this unexpected behavior?

Your example rules don't show this, but if this is what your real rules are doing -- this is clearly the issue.

**Never** reference the global in your when clause.

Globals are not facts; updates to them are not visible to the engine. If you modify `Applicant`, you can call `update($applicant)` and the drools engine will reevaluate the rule matches based on the new state of the inputs and you'll see new rules firing (or not, as depends on the state of the working memory.) You cannot call `update( myList )`.

You can put new items in the global all you'd like, but you must not attempt to reference its state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not checking the state of the global in my when clause. What I meant was, I am adding a value to this global list in the rule. Can that cause such a situation. Sorry for the confusion. Is there no other possibility of this situation occurring then. I am leaning towards there being a problem with the KieContainer being a singleton. Perhaps we are sharing the global variable among multiple sessions. I may be completely wrong here though

Comment: Kiecontainers are singletons in my applications. Sharing lists across multiple sessions is more likely to cause concurrent modification exceptions. Unfortunately all I have to go on are the artifacts in your post, which includes a set of rules that don't behave as described, and a question which would explain what's going on but which now you're indicating isn't actually the case.

Comment: I have added some more code in case it helps find the issue. With some more research I found this question stackoverflow.com/questions/13433020/… which mentions that global variables in stateless sessions may be causing the issue. Also regarding the rules, the original ones in my code are the same as given in the example. The only difference is that there are multiple rules present in multiples files.

Comment: If that's the case why did you even ask the explicit question about globals in the when clause? Because that _would_ cause this behavior. The code and rules in your question do not illustrate the behavior you're seeing.